# How do you say "Don't get too close!" in Latin?

Tags: syntax

So, how would you say "*Don't get too close.*" in Latin? I know the Latin for "*getting close*" is "*approximare*", so my guess is that it starts with "*Noli approximare...*", but I don't know how to say the rest.

Comment: "Noli nimis accedere!" Sounds good.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças What is the difference between "accedere" and "approximare"?

Comment: I know "approximare" as "to be near" "approach" and "accedere" as "to come near to" You were asking about "to get close" I just find "accedere" better in the context.